# Performance problems with many entities in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a rolling scene based game. I'm loading all the entities from a XML file and create them in the Loading Scene.

I recently increased the game width, and, by doing so, I now have about 300 entities (instead of about 100) in the whole level. This causes a performance problem: the game is "Lagging" \ "jumping" and everything moves slowly.

I'm loading the entities with the "LevelLoader".

I tried to add:

```
levelObject.setCullingEnabled(true);
```

before returning the object in :

```
public IEntity onLoadEntity(final String pEntityName, final Attributes pAttributes){...}
```

and also set Dithering in the engineOptions:

```
engineOptions.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);
```

but it didn't help...

I'm implementing the sprite created from XML as Matin does in his tutorial:

http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-11.html

Is there a better way to handle such a high number of entities? Or is there another way to improve the performance?

Comment: Are there more details about your implementation that you can reveal? From what you've posted it's very difficult to pin-point your problem. As sm4 pointed out, a SpriteBatch can help you, but only under certain circumstances and without knowing more about your application providing relevant suggestions will be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that there are many things that you can do. Bad news - there's no magic switch to set to true to make your game run faster.

1. Make sure that whatever you are doing in a loop is optimized. For example if you check in each loop cycle for some difficult condition for each sprite.
2. Dithering won't help you. Please first understand what it does :)
3. Culling helps a lot, but it is turned on by default, so you don't have to turn it on yourself
4. Instead of using many sprites (300 is not that much though), try [SpriteBatch](http://www.andengine.org/forums/updates/spritebatch-2x-performance-improvement-anyone-t3613.html). This should help you the most in this case. I suppose you use a lot of entities that look the same. There's when the Sprite batch comes handy.

I expect you now ask: How to use the SpriteBatch? Well the link explains it, so please first go through the code there, try to understand it, implement it and if you hit a wall again, ask a new question specifically about it :)